# GRANT Permission to dynamic user SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-grant

The username that I give a permission is changeable. Therefore I would like to write a SQL like following;

```
grant ANALYZE ANY DICTIONARY to (select USERNAME from DBA_USERS where DEFAULT_TABLESPACE = 'MCP_DATA');
```

However, it gives an error. 
All comments and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```
DECLARE
  username DBA_USERS.USERNAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT USERNAME
  INTO   username
  FROM   DBA_USERS
  WHERE  DEFAULT_TABLESPACE = 'MCP_DATA';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ANALYZE ANY DICTIONARY TO ' || username;
END;
/
```